# Vuetify focus input inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to focus on the next dynamically inserted input, I can focus foobar_x but not the ones in the v-for loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/Moloth/pen/qPRGvz

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: "xxxxxx",
    phones: [
      {number: "0000000"},
      {number: "1111111"},    
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    focusPhones: function() {
      this.$refs.foobar_1.focus()
    },
    focusTest: function() {
      this.$refs.foobar_x.focus()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-text-field label="foobar_x" ref="foobar_x" v-model="test"></v-text-field>
  <div v-for="(value, i) in phones" :key="i">
    <v-text-field :label="'foobar_'+i" :ref="'foobar_'+i" v-model="phones[i].number"></v-text-field>
    
  </div>
  <v-btn @click.native="focusPhones()">Focus foobar_1</v-btn>
  <v-btn @click.native="focusTest()">Focus foobar_x</v-btn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you add a `ref` value to an element in a `v-for` loop an array will be generated in `this.$refs['name-of-your-value']`, and the reference to that element or component will be pushed to that array.

So, because you are dynamically adding a ref via `:ref="'foobar_'+i"`, the reference to those components will be at `this.$refs.foobar_0[0]` and `this.$refs.foobar_1[0]`. But, if you just specify the same `ref` value (say `foobar_y`), Vue will do the indexing work for you and your components will be accessible at `this.$refs.foobar_y[0]` and `this.$refs.foobar_y[1]`.

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: "xxxxxx",
    phones: [
      {number: "0000000"},
      {number: "1111111"},    
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    focusPhones: function() {
      this.$refs.foobar_y[1].focus()
    },
    focusTest: function() {
      this.$refs.foobar_x.focus()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-text-field label="foobar_x" ref="foobar_x" v-model="test"></v-text-field>
  <div v-for="(value, i) in phones" :key="i">
    <v-text-field :label="'foobar_'+i" ref="foobar_y" v-model="phones[i].number"></v-text-field>
    
  </div>
  <v-btn @click.native="focusPhones()">Focus foobar_y[1]</v-btn>
  <v-btn @click.native="focusTest()">Focus foobar_x</v-btn>
</div>
```